# Formatting decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment to create a class to add complex numbers, I have the program fully working aside from decimal place format, The expected output file the instructor gave has 6 places after the decimal point, my output is giving two.

```
class ComplexNumber:  

    def __init__(self, R, I):   
        self.R, self.I = R, I                      


    def add(self, other):  
        self.R = self.R + other.R 
        self.I = self.I + other.I
        return ComplexNumber(self.R, self.I)


    def __str__(self):

        OutStr = str(self.R) 
        OutStr += ' + '
        OutStr += str(self.I)
        OutStr += ' * ' 
        OutStr += 'i'
        return str(OutStr)

InputFile = open('input.txt')
OutFile = open('output.txt', 'w')

for lines in InputFile.readlines(): 
    values = [float(i) for i in lines.split()]
    N_1 = ComplexNumber(values[0], values[1])
    N_2 = ComplexNumber(values[2], values[3])
    N_3 = ComplexNumber.add(N_1, N_2)
    print(N_3)
```

Comment: Python already has complex numbers, by the way: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals

Comment: Altering `self.R` and `self.I` in the `add` method is wrong, by the way. `z = x.add(y)` shouldn't alter `x`, but it does with your code.

Comment: this is my first time writing a class, so if there is anything different you can recommend please do.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.R:.6g} + {self.I} * i'
```

Explanation:

`{0}` tells format to print the first argument.

Everything after the colon specifies the format_spec.

`.6` sets the precision to 6.

`g` removes insignificant zeros

Comment: We actually want the insignificant digits, as crazy as that is. This is the expected output file given by instructor, mind you the input didn't have any decimals beyond 2 spaces, this is the issue i'm having

Comment: 0.000000 + 0.000000 * i
12.000000 + 8.000000 * i
-5.000000 + -3.000000 * i
5.830000 + 4.200000 * i
 Is expected output